# Не воспроизводится видео Android api < 23 MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer, exoplayer

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь воспроизвести видео через SurfaceView + mediaplayer.
На 23 версии android все работает отлично. Но если версия ниже 23, то выдает ошибку:

> E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
>
> E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)

В коде все нормально. На api 23 работает нормально.

Видео разные. Вот на каком [тестирую](http://www.avtosushi.ru/video/FREE%20Slow%20motion%20video_Water%20drops.mp4).

При этом есть видео которые воспроизводятся (mp4 низкого качества), а есть не работающие. Приложение под Android TV (думаю не особо важно).

Попробовал с помощью ExoPlayer:

> I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
>
> I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
>
> W/OMXNodeInstance: [1:google.h264.decoder] component does not support
>   metadata mode; using fallback
>
> E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/
>   err -1010
>
> I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
>
> E/SoftAVC: Decoder failed: -2
>
> E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
>
> E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
>
> E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in
>   state 6

Для наглядности код

```
    private void setupVideoView() {

    emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    emVideoView.setVideoPath(FILE_PATH);
}

@Override
public void onPrepared() {
    emVideoView.start();
}
```

В обоих случаях черный экран вместо видео. Как можно исправить это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Этот вопрос уже задавался](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790824/mediaplayer-should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-kitkat)

Насколько я понял, вам необходимо добавить строчку: `mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`

На всякий случай вот [пример](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer) из доков.